# Google Sheet program doesn't work when it does

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Yeah, so my Google Sheet program doesn't work despite the fact that it actually does. You see, my program is that it creates a custom menu with a custom function which then actives that function when I click on it. I was able to get both my custom menu and custom function to work but after a while, it just up and said that it doesn't work. Specifically, I get a

> Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context

for `createEmptyMenu` and

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of undefined"

for `settingA`. When I create a new project and copy and paste my work, the project and program works just fine. So why does my program suddenly not work after a while? I also have an `onEdit` trigger if that helps.

```
function createEmptyMenu() {
   var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("⚙️ Admin Settings");
   menu.addItem("Seperate Rows", "settingA");
   menu.addToUi();
}

function settingA() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssLength = ss.getSheets().length;
  
  for (j = 2; j <= ssLength; j++) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[j];
    var num = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getNumRows();
.........
```

Comment: In our world [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) are functions which are used as a replacement for cell formulas so calling them from a menu doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
function settingA() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getSheets().forEach((sh,i)=>{
    let num = getColumnHeight(1,sh,ss);
  })  
}

function getColumnHeight(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  const rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse()
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
}
```

ranges like getRange('A1:A') tend to return nulls between lastRow and maxRows